# AppDelegate already defines FinishedLaunching

Tags: c#, ios, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to follow [Azure's guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started/) to setup iOS push notification. But when it comes to step 6, that says

> In `AppDelegate.cs`, update FinishedLaunching() to match the
>   following:
>
> ```
> public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
> {
>    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
>       var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new NSSet ());
>
>       UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
>       UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
>    } else {
>       UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
>       UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
>    }
>
>    return true;
> }
> ```

I get this error `Type 'AppDelegate' already defines a member called 'FinishedLaunching' with the same parameter types.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, do you have another `FinishedLaunching` method in your `AppDelegate` class? If so, remove it.

Comment: What Nikita said. It's likely that you have two definitions of the same method.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have not seen, that Xamarin was using it. Now I am wondering, why RegisteredForRemoteNotification is not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I did not see, that Xamarin has created it's own FinishedLaunching, when the project is created